# Display returned value as 0 instead of NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to SELECT data from my database. If the returned value = NULL I want to display `0` instead of `NULL`.

I am trying it with the following statement:

```
IF(inv1.id != '', COUNT(inv1.id), '0') AS invoice_count,
```

When I run the statement I still get `NULL`. Does someone know why I am still getting `NULL`?

Here is my full statement:

```
SELECT cus.cus_id, cus.name_cus, cus.contact, cus.place, cus.address, inv1.invoice_count, inv1.invoice_total, cus.status, cus.id FROM cus
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT inv1.cus_id,
    IFNULL(COUNT(inv1.id), 0) AS invoice_count,
    IFNULL(CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(SUM(inv1.total),2)), 0) as invoice_total 
    FROM invoice inv1 
    GROUP BY inv1.cus_id
) inv1 
ON cus.cus_id = inv1.cus_id 
WHERE cus.user_id='2'
```

Comment: can you please provide table schema & a complete query ?

Comment: Is the `invoice` a table or schema?

Comment: Invoice is a table

Comment: Why do you use `invoce` table in `FROM` clause? The `invoce`'s fields are not used in the query.

Comment: `inv1` is also `invoice`

Comment: The name of `invoice` is changed to `inv1`at `FROM invoice inv1`

Comment: Oh... The `inv1` is alias of table `invoice`, isn't it? Sorry, now I have understood.

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: The `IFNULL` should work perfectly. It is possible that the reason of trouble is in aliases using. Try to rewrite your query without `inv1` alias (use `invoice` instead). And make feedback, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function of MySQL.

```
IFNULL(COUNT(inv1.id), '0') AS invoice_count
```

Update query : Please use below query

```
SELECT cus.cus_id, cus.name_cus, cus.contact, cus.place, 
cus.address, ifnull(inv1.invoice_count,0), 
ifnull(inv1.invoice_total,0), 
cus.status, cus.id FROM cus
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT inv1.cus_id,
    COUNT(inv1.id) AS invoice_count,
    FORMAT(SUM(inv1.total),2) as invoice_total
   FROM invoice inv1
   GROUP BY inv1.cus_id
) inv1
ON cus.cus_id = inv1.cus_id
WHERE cus.user_id='2';
```

Comment: @John, see [`IFNULL` function description](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull). If first expression returns `NULL` then the funtion will return second expression. @shashankqv are right.

Comment: @john share your complete query here.

Comment: SELECT cus.cus_id, cus.name_cus, cus.contact, cus.place, 
    cus.address, ifnull(inv1.invoice_count,0), ifnull(inv1.invoice_total,0), 
    cus.status, cus.id FROM cus
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT inv1.cus_id,
        COUNT(inv1.id) AS invoice_count,
        FORMAT(SUM(inv1.total),2) as invoice_total
       FROM invoice inv1
       GROUP BY inv1.cus_id
    ) inv1
    ON cus.cus_id = inv1.cus_id
    WHERE cus.user_id='2'

Comment: Yes, I think its working. At least when everything is NULL. I am gonna check if it will still work when I add any value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
IFNULL(COUNT(inv1.id), 0) AS invoice_count
```

IFNULL returns the **expression 1** which is `COUNT(inv1.id)` in your case if it is not `NULL` else returns the **expression 2** which is `0` in your case.

Comment: @john: Your last hope : `COALESCE(count(inv1.id), 0) AS invoice_count`

Comment: Should I run it like: `IFNULL(COALESCE(count(inv1.id), 0)) AS invoice_count` or just `COALESCE(count(inv1.id), 0) AS invoice_count`?

Comment: @john : The latter. I knew the only two methods to do so. Try to run them individually and see if they are working. If yes then try to rectify the problem when you put things together. And to help you more with the syntax and other things try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

Comment: No, its still the same